# Mid level Trigonometry problem

Tags: trigonometry

I want the solution of this problem

If $\tan^3 \theta + \cot^3 \theta = 52$, find the value of $\tan^2 \theta + \cot^2 \theta$

Comment: Really? Good...and your question *is* ?

Comment: "You can't always get what you want"  (see the Rolling Stones).

Comment: @Raunit Singh  It will be best for you, me, and all concerned  that you phrase your unedited declarative statement  ("I want...") into a real question (using a word in the set from the set {how, why, when, ... }, e.g..  And while you are at the task of editing your question, please add what you've tried, and/or what you know, so that we can best answer.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: use that $$\tan(\theta)=\frac{1}{\cot(\theta)}$$ with $$\cot(\theta)\ne 0$$
setting $$\tan(\theta)=t$$ you will get the equation $$t^6-52t^3+1=0$$ and this is a special quadratic equation

Comment: I have tried it but cant get the answers

Comment: But how to Solve this equation .

Comment: you can set $t^3=x$ and you will get the equation $$x^2-52x+1=0$$

Comment: But sir how that equation will help , the roots won't be rational .

Comment: not all in our life is rational

Comment: this is solid math (+1)

Comment: ???????????????¿?????????????????????????????????

Comment: you will need only $$\tan(\theta)$$ or $$\cot(\theta)$$

Comment: What exactly have you tried. Raunit?  Dr. Sonnhard Graubner has provided great hints, and follow up comments...Unless you have a very specific question about a specific part of solving the equation: AND are willing to add TO your posted question, it seems that your are wasting and/or taking advantage of our time and goodwill.